# How to perform an operation when the user assigns a value to a class instance via dot notation?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple class for working with Timecode `$var = [timecode]::new("00:00:02:00", 12)`:

```
FrameRate  : 12
FrameCount : 24
TimeStamp  : 00:00:02:00
Hours      : 0
Minutes    : 0
Seconds    : 2
Frames     : 0
```

And I can modify it through methods, for example `$var.removeFrames(12)`:

```
FrameRate  : 12
FrameCount : 12
TimeStamp  : 00:00:01:00
Hours      : 0
Minutes    : 0
Seconds    : 1
Frames     : 0
```

This is nice and all but I also want to account for the user being able to modify any of the properties via dot notation.

As it stands, I can do `$var.seconds = 4` but only the `seconds` property is updated, all the other properties are not reevaluated.

Is it possible to know when the user has opted to use dot notation assignment so I can also update the other properties?

Comment: In PowerShell you will need to use ScriptProperties, there is no concept of getters / setters for PowerShell classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PowerShell you will need to use [ScriptProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptproperty?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0), there is no concept of [getters / setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) for PowerShell classes. See also [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) where this was proposed but never implemented.

```bash
class Test {
    [int] $A
    [int] $B
    [int] $Result

    Test([int] $A, [int] $B) {
        $this.A = $A
        $this.B = $B
        $this.PSObject.Properties.Add([psscriptproperty]::new(
            'Result', { $this.A + $this.B }))
    }
}

$test = [Test]::new(5, 5)
$test.Result # 10
$test.A = 10
$test.Result # 15
$test.B = 10
$test.Result # 20
```

In C# you could use a getter here to achieve the same:

```bash
Add-Type '
public class TestCs
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return A + B;
        }
    }
}'

$test = [TestCs]@{ A = 5; B = 5 }
$test.Result # 10
$test.A = 10
$test.Result # 15
$test.B = 10
$test.Result # 20
```

Comment: This looks simple enough a solution, Thank you. Man I wish I knew so C#. I might just pick it up to fill in some Powershell gaps. I left a comment to that Github link, hopefully they see that there is a need for this feature. Cheers!

Comment: @Ralf_Reddings it depends on how deep you want to go, I really love C# but thats personally of course.